# Where do you put CSS files in a rails app directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

Where should i create a folder to house my CSS files within my rails app directory??

Comment: What is your documentation?  This is part of the general layout of the rails directories.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

for Rails 2.x : public/stylesheets

Comment: so then how do you link to this stylesheet??

Comment: either <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'file' %> or use a regular link to the path /stylesheets/file.css .

Comment: If you had a stylesheet named foo.css, you would put this in the head section of whatever view needed it.
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "foo" %>

Answer (score 20):

For Rails 3.1+ apps, you should use the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). Place stylesheets in `app/assets/stylesheets/` if they are specific to your application. You can also put them at `vendor/assets/stylesheets/` if they are external (say if they are stylesheets for a javascript plugin.)

After that, you will include stylesheets using the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` if it is included in your layout file (see other answers for how to do this.)

Answer (score 9):

`/app` is for programmatic content (your models, views, controllers, layouts, partials, etc). `/public` is for your static content (html, images, stylesheets, javascripts, etc)

so the correct place for your stylesheets would be `/public/stylesheets`. If you follow this convention, you can use the `stylesheet_link_tag` helper, so if you put `style.css` into `/public/stylesheets`, then

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "style" %>
```

will get rendered as

```
<link href="/stylesheets/style.css?1232285206" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 4):

For Rails 4:

1) Add your `.css` file in `app/assets/stylesheets`

2) In your view file `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'uploaded_file_name' %>`

Answer (score 3):

put it in public/stylesheets

then use

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "style_sheet_file_name" %>
```

in your

Answer (score 0):

`stylesheet_link_tag` takes arrays of stylesheets as well as a string.

For example:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag %w[ screen print ]
```

There are some great examples of using the `stylesheet_link_tag` helper at [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag).