# CSS in a Rails nested-form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, nested-forms

I'm new to Rails, so bear with me.

I have a view file called new.html.erb that renders a form (_form.html.erb) that uses a nested form  (_traveler.form.erb). These are located in the app/views/traveling_parties directory. I'm trying to use CSS to style this form.

I've seen the question " [Where do you put CSS files in a rails app directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058886/where-do-you-put-css-files-in-a-rails-app-directory) ", so I stuck my css file (newgame.css) in public/stylesheets and put the following tag at the top of my new.html.erb file:

```
<head>
<%= stylesheet_form_tag "newgame" %>
</head>
```

In my CSS file, I have a test ID:

```
#test
{
    background: #000;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

And I applied this to a div in my new.html.erb file

But it doesn't seem to do anything... Is there anything I'm doing blatantly wrong? Is there any other information I can provide?

Comment: Which Version of Rails are you using??

Comment: see RailsCasts at bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check http://railscasts.com/ for episodes about views and layouts (e.g. search there)

The answer depends on which version of Rails you are using.

In general you could have multiple layouts in a Rails application.

If you have just one layout, then **your CSS file will be in the default location for your Rails version**.

e.g. (assuming you are using SCSS)

public/stylesheets/application.scss **in Rails 2.x**

app/stylesheets/application.scss **in Rails 3.x**

**Check also this RailsGuide:**

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

**Check these two RailsCasts:** (in particular in regards to the Asset Pipeline)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline

http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1