# where do we set a scaffold.css file in my ruby on rails application?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

My ruby on rails app is completely functional but I want to style it. Where and how do I set my css file to display properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do you put CSS files in a rails app directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058886/where-do-you-put-css-files-in-a-rails-app-directory)

Answer (score 2):

Put your all css in app/assets/stylesheet folder.

Put your all js in app/assets/javascript folder

& include them by the following code

```
<%= javascript_incldue_tag "file.js" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "filename.css %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by resetting my rails server and placing my css in the assets/stylesheet folder. Really good to know facts for future ROR developers.